# After installing memcached, unable to locate memcached.so

Tags: installation, memcached, ubuntu-8.04

I've installed memcached on my  ubuntu server (8.04), but after

apt-get install memcached

and successfully installing it, it does not appear in php.ini.

I have tested memcached by doing

telnet 127.0.0.1 11211

and executing commands such as  STATS;  success.

I have placed
extension=memcache.so in my .ini file.

However, i have searched the computer using

find / -name memcache.so

and it comes up empty.

Can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install it?  Installing the memcache server does not install the php module.